# Angular's bindings don't work with elements added in directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My directive is

```
myApp.directive('myRequired', function ($compile, gettextCatalog) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var noticeContainer = '<div class="inputError" ng-show="showSomeNotices" translate>{{errorMessage}}</div>';
            element.after(noticeContainer);

        scope.$on("submitstart", function (event, data) {
            scope.showSomeNotices = false;
            if (!element.val()) {
                scope.errorMessage = gettextCatalog.getString("Empty field");                
                scope.showSomeNotices = true;

            }
        });
    }};
});
```

But ng-show and bracets `{{errorMessage}}` ignores connected variables. I always see `{{errorMessage}}` as text on my page. How to fix?

Comment: You have to compile `noticeContainer`(using $compile) div to `ng-show`/`any angular bindings` to enable on that DOM

Comment: Use $compile inside link function.

Comment: @PankajParkar, can you tell me what exactly I have to do? Because `$complie(noticeContainer)(scope)` doesn't work.

Comment: errorMessage & showSomeNotices scope variable belongs to same scope which you are compiling?

Comment: @PankajParkar, yes. I can see in debugger that errorMessage and showSomeNotices inside scope variable that I use in $compile call.

Comment: Could you please create a plunkr?

Comment: @PankajParkar, I'm afraid, I can't. But the usage is pretty easy: `<input type="text" class="defaultInput login" placeholder="{{'Login'|translate}}" my-required ng-model="account.number" required />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentioned in the comments above you must compile the string like this:

```
…
var noticeContainer = '<div class="inputError" ng-show="showSomeNotices" translate>{{errorMessage}}</div>',
    content = $compile(noticeContainer)(scope);

element.after(content);
…
```

I've created a plunkr for you: https://plnkr.co/edit/9HKoLg401Thip2cLHYsb?p=preview

Comment: @splash27 I've edited my answer with little modification and a plunkr

Comment: I don't know what was wrong with my code. But when I copied and pasted your code from plunkr, it started to work. Thank you!